# Modify data cell of table with condition in Jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have made a page that shows a table with two columns: Users and their Points.
I want to make bold the data cell that has the name of the User session. The table is made in a Jinja for loop. So I created a .bold class in CSS and a condition inside the loop. But it doesn't work at all.

I am very new at code so I am sorry if my question is very simple. Thanks in advance.

I think this is the relevant part of my index.

```
    if request.method == 'GET':

        user = session['user_id']
        userN = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=?", user)
        username = userN[0]["username"]
      
        return render_template('index.html', fixtures=fixtures, username=username, homeScore=homeScore, awayScore=awayScore, userScore=userScore, userHome=userHome, userAway=userAway, usuarios=usuarios)
```

My HTML:

```
            {% for user in usuarios %}

            <tr>
                {% if user["username"] == "{{ username }}"  %}
                <td  class="bold">{{ user["username"] }}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td>{{ user["username"] }}</td>
                {% endif %}

                <td>{{ user["puntos"] }}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: You should check your for loop in the template. I don't see 'usuarios ' declared anywhere in the render_template. Also, what do you expect to happen with the if conditional?

Comment: Oh, I copy-pasted without the usuarios=usuarios, but in my file it is there. I except that if the text of user is equal to my variable username, the td class is set to 'bold'. I am thinking the wrong way, right?

Comment: Are you sure there is a parameter called "text" in the objet "user" inside the list "usuarios" that have the same value as the variable "username"? Shouldn't you use user['username'] == "{{username}}" ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rodrigo! yes, that was wrong. But I changed it to  user['username'] == "{{username}}" and nothing happened. I forgot to say that 'usuarios' is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @RodrigoCava basically what he said. You should also note that "username" is a database query object, you can't really use it in equality comparison the way you did there.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from "{{ username }}"

Comment: Please note that in your current code you are check if username['username'], lets say "Mark" is equal to username, which is a database query object. Your code fails there.

Comment: @Maiels I just tried with a simple string like {% if user["username"] == "example"  %} and it worked. Why I can't use the variable username in equality comparison?

Comment: @franjapaez as I mentioned above, "username" is a database query object. To understand this better go in your view function and try to print the username object with print(username).

Comment: @franjapaez here is more [info on cursors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) (aka your execute statement). They return an iterator. If you want to get values from the username variable you have to iterate over it properly.

Comment: @Maiels thank you very much! I tried this: in my app.py at index, created a variable called userN with the database query and then: username = userN[0]["username"]. I printed it and it is, as I expected,  "Mark". I hoped this would make the <td> bold but it didn't!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers.
It finally worked!

I followed the advice of RodrigoCava and Maiels and got it. It was an issue with the database query and also I was putting {{ }} where I shouldn't.
This is the final code:

```
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':

        user = session['user_id']
        usern = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=?", user)
        username = usern[0]["username"]
```

And the HTML

```
 {% for user in usuarios %}

                <tr>
                    {% if user["username"] ==  username   %}
                    <td  class="bold">{{ user["username"] }}</td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td>{{ user["username"] }}</td>
                    {% endif %}

                    <td>{{ user["puntos"] }}</td>
```